# How to Calculate Timespan from a Specific Datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-workbench

I'm working with a database on MySQL workbench and I have a datetime value: "2021-01-01 00:00:00". I need to calculate the timespan or difference between this specific datetime and the current date and time. Ideally, I'd like the result in various units (days, hours, minutes).

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', GETDATE()) AS days_difference;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html - NOTE there is no getdate() in mysql..

Answer (score 1):

DATEDIFF is only used to calculate date difference. Instead you can use **TIMESTAMPDIFF** built in function like this:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', NOW()) AS days_difference,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', NOW()) AS hours_difference,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', NOW()) AS minutes_difference;
```

More about TIMESTAMPDIFF: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php